# Programmatically check if imregtform converged

Tags: matlab

Using `'DisplayOptimization',1` in `imregtform` its possible to see the optimizer diverging. Or even that the optimizer exceeded the max number of iterations

```
OnePlusOneEvolutionaryOptimizer: Maximum number of iterations (400) exceeded.
```

How can you get this information back using code?

My initial plan was to fidget with `imregtform`, but it looks like MATLAB's implementation is piping into `regmex`.  Is there maybe some wacky way to catch the text output?

Comment: Do you need more help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for [`evalc()`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalc.html).

call it as

```
[text, output]=evalc(myfun(inputs));
```

and it will capture in `text` anything that would have been written in the command window. You can then just fiddle with it with string/char based functions to obtain whatever information you want.